# How to display detail view on separate page using Vuejs

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, components

I have a page where there is multiple cases and when i click on case it shows the detail against this case on same page.
I have attached the screen shot[image]

as you can see two cases are showing 1) ublox and 2) test case when i click any of them you can see on top detail against this case is appeared.

But I do not want to display these detail on this page I wan to display these detail on separate page when i click any of these case. I am new to vuejs can anyone please help me on this?
Your help will be really appreciated.

My code of vue:

```
    <template>

    <div>
        <div class="content">

            <div class="container-fluid">

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                <h3 class="card-title"></h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body table-responsive p-0" style="height: 300px; width: 100%">
                                <table class="table table-hover">
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>ID</th>
                                        <th>User Id</th>
                                        <th>Case Id</th>
                                        <th>Message Title</th>
                                        <th>Process Type</th>
                                        <th>Description</th>
                                        <th>Data Load</th>
                                        <th>Message Code</th>
                                        <th>Log Type</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                    <tr v-for="list in lists">
                                        <td>{{list.id}}</td>
                                        <td>{{list.user_id}}</td>
                                        <td>{{list.case_id}}</td>
                                        <td>{{list.message_title}}</td>
                                        <td>{{list.process_type}}</td>
                                        <td>{{list.description}}</td>
                                        <td>{{list.data_load}}</td>
                                        <td>{{list.msg_code}}</td>
                                        <td>{{list.log_type}}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- /.card-header -->
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body table-responsive p-0" style="height: 300px;">
                                <table class="table table-hover">
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Case Name</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                    <tr v-for="kase in cases" :key="kase.id" v-on:click="clickList(kase)">
                                        <td>{{kase.name}}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-6">

                        <div class="card card-info">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                <h3 class="card-title">Add New Case</h3>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.card-header -->
                            <!-- form start -->
                            <form class="form-horizontal" @submit.prevent="onSubmit" @keydown="form.errors.clear()">
                                <div class="card-body" style="height: 239px;">
                                    <div class="form-group row">
                                        <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required autocomplete="name" autofocus placeholder="Name" v-model="form.name">
                                            <span class="invalid-feedback d-block" role="alert" v-if="form.errors.has('name')" v-text="form.errors.get('name')"></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.card-body -->
                                <div class="card-footer">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" :disabled="form.errors.any()">Add Group</button>
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.card-footer -->
                            </form>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->

        </div>
        <!-- /.content -->

    </div>

</template>

<script>

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                cases: [],
                lists: [],
                form: new Form({
                    'name': ''
                })
            }
        },
        created() {
            axios.get('/new-case')
                .then(({data}) => this.cases = data);
        },

        methods: {
            clickList (Kase) {
                axios.get(`/case-log/${Kase.id}`).then(response => this.lists = response.data);
            },
            onSubmit(){
                this.form
                    .post('/new-case')
                    .then(kase => this.cases.push(kase));
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

and my web.php

```
      Route::get('/case-log/{id}', 'CaseLogController@index');
```

My Controller:

```
class CaseLogController extends Controller
{
    public function index($id)
    {
        $case = kase::with('sockets')->find($id);
        return $case->sockets;
    }
}
```

your help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

```
           <template>

    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="card-title"></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body table-responsive p-0" style="height: 300px; width: 100%">
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>User Id</th>
                        <th>Case Id</th>
                        <th>Message Title</th>
                        <th>Process Type</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Data Load</th>
                        <th>Message Code</th>
                        <th>Log Type</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="list in lists">
                        <td>{{list.id}}</td>
                        <td>{{list.user_id}}</td>
                        <td>{{list.case_id}}</td>
                        <td>{{list.message_title}}</td>
                        <td>{{list.process_type}}</td>
                        <td>{{list.description}}</td>
                        <td>{{list.data_load}}</td>
                        <td>{{list.msg_code}}</td>
                        <td>{{list.log_type}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</template>
<script>

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                lists: [],
            }
        },
        created() {
            const uniqueIdentifierToFetchTheDetailsFromTheDatabase  this.$route.params.id
            axios.get(`/case-log/${Kase.id}`).then(response => this.lists = response.data);
        },
    }
</script>
```

This is updated:

```
      <template>

    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="card-title"></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body table-responsive p-0" style="height: 300px; width: 100%">
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>User Id</th>
                        <th>Case Id</th>
                        <th>Message Title</th>
                        <th>Process Type</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Data Load</th>
                        <th>Message Code</th>
                        <th>Log Type</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="list in lists">
                        <td>{{list.id}}</td>
                        <td>{{list.user_id}}</td>
                        <td>{{list.case_id}}</td>
                        <td>{{list.message_title}}</td>
                        <td>{{list.process_type}}</td>
                        <td>{{list.description}}</td>
                        <td>{{list.data_load}}</td>
                        <td>{{list.msg_code}}</td>
                        <td>{{list.log_type}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</template>
<script>

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                lists: [],
            }
        },
        created() {
            const id = this.$route.params.id
            axios.get(`/case-log/${Kase.id}`).then(response => this.lists = response.data);
        },
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Does simply making `<td>{{kase.name}}</td>` a hyperlink not meet your requirements?

Comment: How I can add hyper link? can you show?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to define your routes using Vue-router. The [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#javascript) shows you how to get started.

Then you need to extract the template of the details into a component, say `DisplayDetailView.vue`

So you will have:

#### DisplayDetailView.vue

```html
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
          <h3 class="card-title"></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body table-responsive p-0" style="height: 300px; width: 100%">
          <table class="table table-hover">
              <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>User Id</th>
                  <th>Case Id</th>
                  <th>Message Title</th>
                  <th>Process Type</th>
                  <th>Description</th>
                  <th>Data Load</th>
                  <th>Message Code</th>
                  <th>Log Type</th>
              </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              <tr v-for="list in lists">
                  <td>{{list.id}}</td>
                  <td>{{list.user_id}}</td>
                  <td>{{list.case_id}}</td>
                  <td>{{list.message_title}}</td>
                  <td>{{list.process_type}}</td>
                  <td>{{list.description}}</td>
                  <td>{{list.data_load}}</td>
                  <td>{{list.msg_code}}</td>
                  <td>{{list.log_type}}</td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

.....
```

When you click on the detail, it will navigate you to the component where details are shown.

Clicking on `Ublox` for example, may have code attached to it as follows

#### ComponentWithCaseName.vue

```html
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="card">
        ...
      <tr v-for="kase in cases" :key="kase.id" v-on:click="handleCaseClick"> // add click handler
          <td>{{kase.name}}</td>
      </tr>
      ......
  </div>
</div>
```

And you have a method in the component where the case name is clicked

```js
methods: {
  handleCaseClick() { // this pushes it to the component that has the display view details i.e DisplayDetailView.vue
    this.$router.push(`/path-to-component-for-view-details/${uniqueIdentifierToFetchTheDetailsFromTheDatabase}')
  }
}
```

In the DisplayDetailView.vue component, you have to grab the unique identifier from the url, using the created/mounted hook, (in this case, I use the created lifecycle hook, but mounted will also work) that you will use to make the database call that will populate the template.

#### DisplayDetailView.vue

```js
 export default {
    data() {
        return {
            cases: [],
            lists: [],
        }
    },
    created() {
    const uniqueIdentifierToFetchTheDetailsFromTheDatabase  this.$route.params.uniqueIdentifierToFetchTheDetailsFromTheDatabase // whatever name you put in the route `e.g if the route is `/path-to-component-for-view-details/:caseId`, you do this.$route.params.caseId
       axios.get(`/case-log/${uniqueIdentifierToFetchTheDetailsFromTheDatabase}`).then(response => this.lists = response.data);
    },
 }
```

This is the general gist of things. You can figure the rest from here. [This](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/data-fetching.html#fetching-after-navigation) will provide you more details.

Comment: Hi thanks for detail overview but i did not understand  created() {
    const uniqueIdentifierToFetchTheDetailsFromTheDatabase  this.$route.params.uniqueIdentifierToFetchTheDetailsFromTheDatabase // whatever name you put in the route `e.g if the route is `/path-to-component-for-view-details/:caseId`, you do this.$route.params.caseId
       axios.get(`/case-log/${uniqueIdentifierToFetchTheDetailsFromTheDatabase}`).then(response => this.lists = response.data);
    },

Comment: what i need to put here in replacement of  uniqueIdentifierToFetchTheDetailsFromTheDatabase

Comment: The created lifecycle hook is use to do things when a component is created. You can make a database call there to fetch the list you will use to populate the template. Using `this.$router.push, you get a url from which you can get the identifier (in your case, id) using this.$route.params.id, if your route is `/path-to-component-for-view-details/:id` or this.$route.params.employeeId, if your route is `/path-to-component-for-view-details/:employeeId` etc.

Comment: When you get the id from the url, you can use it to make the db call. In your case, axios.get(`/case-log/${Kase.id}`).then(response => this.lists =response.data);

Comment: I have added my detail view template please check and guide me where  I am wrong

Comment: sorry for silly question but do i need to replace  const uniqueIdentifierToFetchTheDetailsFromTheDatabase with  const id ?

Comment: I only used `uniqueIdentifierToFetchTheDetailsFromTheDatabase` as a description. You can name the variable whatever you like. A good name in your case will be `caseId`.  
`const caseId = this.$route.params.id`; (again, depending on what your put as the params in your route, using vue-router). Your API call then becomes
axios.get(`/case-log/${caseId}`).then(response => this.lists = response.data) . Do you understand?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219361/discussion-between-shahzad-shah-and-tony).

Comment: can u please come on chat>?

Comment: are u there, i am confused on this